# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined (React)

Tags: function, reactjs, render, dry

I've got a react component that renders content conditionally, but it's a bit verbose and repetitive. I've tried to wrap the repeated code in a function which I then call later (the output dependent on whatever argument I give the function) but this isn't working.

### Original (verbose) solution:

```
render() {

  const userId = parseInt(this.props.params.userId)
  const {posts} = this.props

  if(userId) {
     const postsForUser = posts.filter( post => post.userId === userId )
     return (
        <div>
           {postsForUser.map( post =>
              <Post {...this.props} post={post} key={post.id} />
           )}
        </div>
     )
  }
  else {
     return (
        <div>
           {this.props.posts.map( post =>
              <Post {...this.props} post={post} key={post.id} />
           )}
        </div>
     )
  }

} // end render()
```

### (Unsuccessful) attempt to trim it down

```
render() {

  const userId = parseInt(this.props.params.userId)

  function renderPostList(postsInput) {
     return (
        <div>
           {postsInput.map( post =>
              <Post {...this.props} post={post} key={post.id} />
           )}
        </div>
     )
  }

  if (userId) {
     const postsForUser = this.props.posts.filter( post => post.userId === userId )
     return renderPostList(postsForUser)
  }
  else {
     return renderPostList(this.props.posts)
  }

}
```

I receive the error: `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

I know the problem is to do with the function's scope, and how `this` is referencing the wrong this (or nothing, in this case) but I struggle to get my head around how to solve this. If anyone can explain what's going wrong specifically in this instance, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Try debuging this.props in the map in both examples. Are those the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by moving the `renderPostList` method out of the `render` method and into the class level.

```
renderPostList = (postsInput) => (
  <div>
    {postsInput.map( post =>
      <Post {...this.props} post={post} key={post.id} />          
    )}
  </div>
)

render() {

  const userId = parseInt(this.props.params.userId)

  if (userId) {
     const postsForUser = this.props.posts.filter( post => post.userId === userId )
     return this.renderPostList(postsForUser)
  }
  else {
     return this.renderPostList(this.props.posts)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the function `renderPostList` to `this` to use the `props` values. Try the following solution:

```js
  var renderPostList = function(postsInput) {
     return (
        <div>
           {postsInput.map( post =>
              <Post {...this.props} post={post} key={post.id} />
           )}
        </div>
     )
  };
  renderPostList.bind(this);
```